# Scraping HTML Text from a <dl> Tag

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a description list that I downloaded from a website with an agenda, and I am trying to create a data.frame without success.
the description list has the following structure:

```
<dl>
<dt> (which contains a <p = "day"> for day)
<dd> (which contains a <p = "hour"> for hour and a <p = "event"> for the event)
```

I managed to extract this data with the following code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("www.mypage.com")
day <- data.frame(day = html_text(html_nodes(url, '.day')))
hour <- data.frame(hour = html_text(html_nodes(url, '.hour')))
event <- data.frame(event = html_text(html_nodes(url, '.event')))

day$ID <- seq.int(nrow(day))
hour$ID <- seq.int(nrow(hour))
event$ID <- seq.int(nrow(event))
```

Then I created a data frame by joining them BY ID.

The problem is when I have this:

```
<dl>
<dt>
<dd>
<dd>
<dd>
```

Which is more than one event for each day. 
How can I create my data.frame, taking into account that I might have several `<dd>` for the same `<dt>`? Thanks!

Comment: Not sharing the URL is (generally) either to avoid showing you're performing illegal/unethical activity OR it's an internal page. The latter is understandable, the former is not. You did not provide a reproducible snippet of HTML (repeating `<dd>`s without content are unhelpful) and there may be other node classes or ids that could help. So, please identify at least the nature of the target URL (some of us don't help content thieves)  and include a better bit of sample data OR provide the URL.

Comment: oh, sorry... I am doing a data vis for the agenda of the President of the Portuguese Republic. The agenda is here: http://www.presidencia.pt/?idc=11&fano=2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dl`/`dt`/`dd` scraping is one of those "Why did HTML creators do this to us" kind of things. This shld get you what you want:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("http://www.presidencia.pt/?idc=11&fano=2016")

# grab ALL the dt/dd elements under each dl into one big node list
entries <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//dl[@id='ms_agend3']/*")

# this finds all of the "dt" elements
starts <- which(xml_name(entries) == "dt")

# this tells us where ^^ "dd"'s stop
ends <- c(starts[-1]-1, length(entries))

# it took 30s for me, so progress bars make the time pass visually
pb <- progress_estimated(length(starts))

# now we iterate over the start/end pairs
map2_df(starts, ends, ~{

  pb$tick()$print() # tick off the progress bar

  # we're only going to work on the part of the node list for this dt/dd set
  start <- .x
  end <- .y

  # get the day
  dt <- html_text(entries[start], trim=TRUE)

  # now iterate over each associated dd and pull out the info
  map_df((start+1):end, ~{
    data_frame(
      hour = html_text(html_node(entries[.x], "div.hora"), trim=TRUE),
      text = html_text(html_node(entries[.x], "div.texto"), trim=TRUE),
    )
  }) %>% 
    mutate(day = dt) # add the day in

}) %>% 
  select(day, hour, text) -> agenda # rearrange and store
```

It's a tad slow due the way it makes data frames but it will capture the day/hour/text of the agendas (including the blank hours which I assume are informational or all-day events).

This:

```
pb <- progress_estimated(length(starts))
map2_df(starts, ends, ~{

  pb$tick()$print()

  start <- .x
  end <- .y

  data_frame(
    hour = html_text(html_nodes(entries[(start+1):end], "div.hora"), trim=TRUE),
    text = html_text(html_nodes(entries[(start+1):end], "div.texto"), trim=TRUE),
    day = html_text(entries[start], trim=TRUE)
  )

}) %>% 
  select(day, hour, text) -> agenda
```

is a bit faster and produces the same results as far as my eyes tell me.

Comment: Amazing!!!! Thinking that I spent nearly three days to find out a solutionl!!! Thank you so much. Thanks.

Comment: This one of the more gnarly bits of scraping out there. XPath 2.0 makes it easier (a bit) but the common scraping libs in R or Python don' have support for it. I'm just glad `xml2` exposes just enough functionality to make these workarounds possible.